# Switch Statement Must Be Exhaustive - Xcode bug?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm really confused about this error that Xcode is throwing me. It says `Switch statement must be exhaustive`. However, I'm 100% positive I'm handling all the cases.

Here is my code:

```
enum Search: Endpoint {
    case sets(query: String?, creator: String?, imagesOnly: Bool?, autocomplete: Bool?, modifiedSince: TimeInterval?, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)
    case classes(query: String, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)
    case universal(query: String, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)

    public var baseURL: String { return QuizletEndpoint.baseURL }
    public var version: Float { return QuizletEndpoint.version }

    public var path: String {
        switch self { // Switch must be exhaustive ERROR.
        case .sets:
            return "search/sets"
        case .classes:
            return "search/classes"
        case .universal:
            return "search/universal"
        }
    }
}
```

**Update #1**
Here are the details regarding my protocol `Endpoint`:

```
 /// Represents an Endpoint for networking.
public protocol Endpoint: URLConvertible, URLRequestConvertible {
    /// The url without any parameters or paths.
    var baseURL: String { get }
    /// The version of the API.
    var version: Float { get }
    /// The path to the resource.
    var path: String { get }
    /// Any parameters to be encoded.
    var params: Parameters { get }
}

public extension Endpoint {

     public func asURL() throws -> URL {
         let finalURL = try baseURL.asURL().appendingPathComponent("\(version)").appendingPathComponent(path)
         return finalURL
     }

     func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
         let finalURL = try asURL()
         let request = URLRequest(url: finalURL)

         return try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: params)
     }
}
```

**Update #2**
Ok, now I'm almost certain that this is an Xcode bug. Adding the `default` clause to my enum produces a compiler warning that the `default` clause never gets executed so the compiler is kind of agreeing the `default` clause is redundant:

```
public var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .sets:
            return "search/sets"
        case .classes:
            return "search/classes"
        case .universal:
            return "search/universal"
        default: return "" // WARNING: Default will never be executed.
        }
 }
```

Am I loosing my mind or is this an Xcode bug? I have tried cleaning the build folder, regular cleaning, rebuilding multiple times and I just can't seem to get this error to go away. I'm starting to believe it's a bug in Xcode since I'm running the beta but I just want to double check and make sure it's not an error on my side.

Comment: Please post *code,* not a screenshot – Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @MartinR will update my question

Comment: @LeoDabus but I'm satisfying all cases

Comment: Your code compiles for me (if I remove the uncleared raw type "Endpoint")

Comment: @MartinR Hmm yeah I don't know what's going on with my build. Xcode-beta has been acting strange lately.

Comment: That's why I asked for a [mcve]!

Comment: What is `Endpoint` ???

Comment: @MartinR It is a protocol let me update my question

Comment: This is definitely a Xcode 9 beta 2 bug. A switch on an enum with a single case `case a(String?, String?, Bool?, Int?, Int?, Int?)` is  correctly detected on exhaustiveness, but not with `case a(String?, String?, Bool?, Bool?, Int?, Int?)`. It somehow depends on the number and types of associated values of the enum case. It does not happen with Xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: @MartinR I have filed a bug report :)

Comment: Apparently it was already filed yesterday: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5279. What is your bug report number?

Comment: I accidentally filed it in bug reporter instead of on the swift.org website. However, my bug report number is: 32941844 @MartinR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write it like this, you won't get an error (Xcode 9 beta 2):

```
import Foundation

enum Search {
    case sets(query: String?, creator: String?, imagesOnly: Bool?, autocomplete: Bool?, modifiedSince: TimeInterval?, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)
    case classes(query: String, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)
    case universal(query: String, page: Int?, perPage: Int?)

    public var baseURL: String { return "" }
    public var version: Float { return 0 }

    public var path: String {
        switch self { // Switch must be exhaustive ERROR.
        case .sets(_, _, _, _, _, _, _):
            return "search/sets"
        case .classes(_, _, _):
            return "search/classes"
        case .universal(_, _, _):
            return "search/universal"
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm going to be doing much matching, I usually prefer to wrap the associated values in separate structs. This makes for simpler patterns and for less work when changing the nature of the associated values. Thus:

```
enum Search {

    struct Sets {
        var query: String?
        var creator: String?
        var imagesOnly: Bool?
        var autocomplete: Bool?
        var modifiedSince: TimeInterval?
        var page: Int?
        var perPage: Int?
    }

    case sets(Sets)

    struct Classes {
        var query: String
        var page: Int?
        var perPage: Int?
    }

    case classes(Classes)

    struct Universal {
        var query: String
        var page: Int?
        var perPage: Int?
    }

    case universal(Universal)

    public var baseURL: String { return "" }
    public var version: Float { return 0 }

    public var path: String {
        switch self { // Switch must be exhaustive ERROR.
        case .sets(_):
            return "search/sets"
        case .classes(_):
            return "search/classes"
        case .universal(_):
            return "search/universal"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But OP's code (without the `(_, ...)` patterns) doesn't produce an error either ...

Comment: Yup that fixed it for me. I'll mark it as accepted in 3 minutes (when it allows me to). Do you know why that is though?

Comment: OP's code doesn't give an error when I put it in an Xcode 8.3.3 playground, but when I paste it into the Xcode 9 beta 2 REPL, it does.

Comment: @MartinR even I'm struggling to understand shouldn't both work?

Comment: Then it might be a beta 2 bug, it compiles with Xcode 9 beta 1, and with Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Hmm yeah I'll file a bug report @MartinR.

Comment: @Harish Curious, do you still see the issue if you have `enum Search: Endpoint` here? Is it working now because you removed `Endpoint`, or because you added the `(_, _, _, _, _, _, _)` stuff to the case statements?

Comment: @DaveWood Because I added the (_, ...)

Comment: @Harish Thanks. So this answer should likely be updated to be clear.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes Swift can't detect that you've got all possible cases.

Your best bet is to just add a `default:` case followed by `break`.

Note however, that your code works fine in Xcode 8.3.3 if you remove the `: Endpoint` type from the `enum`. What is that type?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to have unnecessary pieces of code. I'm satisfying all cases as shown above.

Comment: Even with associated values, the compiler generally detects if the switch statement is exhaustive. Your statement is not true in general.

Comment: Yes, so it seems. Copying and pasting his code works, once you remove `: Endpoint`. So it looks like it's something to do with whatever that type is.  Updating my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

XCode checks if the switch statement is exhaustive only if you're switching enums. For every other case, it checks if there is a default statement, and if not, it puts up a warning.

You need to include a default block for the compiler's sake but don't have anything for it to do, the break keyword comes in handy:

```
public var path: String {
    switch self { // Switch must be exhaustive ERROR.
    case .sets:
        return "search/sets"
    case .classes:
        return "search/classes"
    case .universal:
        return "search/universal"
   default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch block is exhaustive when working with `enum` types. Even a switching on `Bool` requires a default block in addition to true and false.So probably compiler will raise

> Every switch statement must be exhaustive. That is, every possible
>   value of the type being considered must be matched by one of the
>   switch cases.

As @Dave Wood says  best bet is to just add a default: case followed by break

Comment: However, I have other enums in my code too and it works fine. I don't understand why this one is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If inside the switch statement you are responsible for RETURN-ing something such as a TableViewCell or CollectionViewCell, all solutions other than the following two will fail:

1. Use UITableViewCell() or UICollectionViewCell().  The "()" will instantiate a null-value version of the item you need to return.
2. Write an error.  It's possible you got this error when refactoring code to add another possibility without incrementing a corresponding case to the switch statement (thus making it non-exhaustive).  In this case you'll want to write a love-letter error message to the future coder to explicitly explain what they forgot.

   return UITableViewCell()

... is code that got me out of this error, but probably more appropriate to write error code if you've indeed been exhaustive.   fatalError() would do the trick.